# How to refresh (i.e. clear text from) an autocompletebox once an item has been selected?

Tags: .net, silverlight, autocompletebox

I'm designing a Silverlight screen where I use an autocompletebox control.

One the item 'foobar' has been selected in the autocompletebox, it's text reads 'foobar'. If a user wants to select the 'quux' value, he has to:

1. delete the text from the control,
2. then to type 'qu' so as to be able to select 'quux'.

Is there a way to performe the step #1 within the SelectionChanged event?

Hint: set the .text property don't work (unless it's followed by some refresh method I don't know of)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SelectionChanged is the wrong event to monitor.

Simply subscribe to the DropDownClosing event, there you'll be able to edit the .text property.